# R function to get the % of the number of a variable inside a factor

Tags: r, bigdata, data-analysis

I am working in the following data.frame with aprox 40.000.000 rows:

```
structure(list(group = c(1003, 1003, 1003, 1003, 1003, 1003, 
1003, 1003, 1003, 1003), t_year = c("2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", 
"2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014"), tmonth = c(3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3), tday = c("02", "02", "02", "02", 
"02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02"), md = c(2507.416244074, 2507.416244074, 
2507.416244074, 2507.416244074, 2507.416244074, 2507.416244074, 
2507.416244074, 2507.416244074, 2507.416244074, 2507.416244074
), st = c(640722481.20599, 640722481.20599, 640722481.20599, 
640722481.20599, 640722481.20599, 640722481.20599, 640722481.20599, 
640722481.20599, 640722481.20599, 640722481.20599), bsc = c(255530.960493802, 
255530.960493802, 255530.960493802, 255530.960493802, 255530.960493802, 
255530.960493802, 255530.960493802, 255530.960493802, 255530.960493802, 
255530.960493802), animal = c("HOUSA000062901617", "HOUSA000006684687", 
"HO982000202967406", "HOUSA000057341913", "HOUSA000139926709", 
"JEUSA000057281350", "HOUSA000056634042", "XXUSA000056639940", 
"HOUSA000064279445", "HOUSA000066846844"), ln = c(6L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 1L), gluc = c(37892.914163, 100000, 606286.6266, 
303143.3133, 303143.3133, 35355.339059, 37892.914163, 37892.914163, 
214354.69251, 37892.914163), gluc_cat = c(1L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L), ol = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("mult", "prim"), class = "factor"), 
    group_size = c("<2000", "<2000", "<2000", "<2000", "<2000", 
    "<2000", "<2000", "<2000", "<2000", "<2000"), date = structure(c(16131, 
    16131, 16131, 16131, 16131, 16131, 16131, 16131, 16131, 16131
    ), class = "Date"), season = c("Spring", "Spring", "Spring", 
    "Spring", "Spring", "Spring", "Spring", "Spring", "Spring", 
    "Spring")), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to understand the behavior of the number of animals in each category along the year. Exemple. In the summer 30% of the animals had gluc <200.000 (Gluc_cat 1), 2% between 200.000 and 400.000 (gluc_cat 2), 15% between 400.000 and 600.000 (gluc_cat 3) and so on and so forth

Trying to make a frequency tab of the number of animals inside each gluc_cat by tyear, ol and season like this:

```
year 2018
ol "prim"
                             season
gluc_cat      Fall    Spring    Summer    Winter
1           16.387677 11.653786 11.719490 10.978675
2            8.307579  5.189070  4.725884  3.862277
3            9.730989  6.571146  3.427911  4.223216
4            3.991289  2.919394  2.877867  4.922916
5            9.224311  4.429528  7.717457 10.597084
6            52.358155 69.237076 69.531391 65.415832

year 2018
ol   "mult"
                           season
gluc_cat      Fall    Spring    Summer    Winter
1           16.387677 11.653786 11.719490 10.978675
2            8.307579  5.189070  4.725884  3.862277
3            9.730989  6.571146  3.427911  4.223216
4            3.991289  2.919394  2.877867  4.922916
5            9.224311  4.429528  7.717457 10.597084
6            52.358155 69.237076 69.531391 65.415832
```

I have tried this code:

```
freq <- prop.table(xtabs(glucose~gluc_cat+season+ord_lact,cabt2),2)*100
freq
```

But I guess I am getting the frequency of the values of glucose, right? And actually I want to know the variation of how many animals are in each category of glucose (gluc_cat) by year, ol and season.

Comment: Do you need something similar to `lapply(split(df, df$ol), function(x)
prop.table(xtabs(gluc~gluc_cat+season,df1), 2))` ?

Comment: I guess with this function I am going to get the frequency of the values of glucose, right? And I need the freq of th number of animals in each gluc_cat ...

Comment: It's unclear for me though. Can you show expected output for the example shown?

Comment: It is the one that I showed on the question. I want to understand the behavior of the number of animals in each category along the year. Exemple. In the summer 30% of the animals had gluc <200.000 (Gluc_cat 1), 2% between 200.000 and 400.000 (gluc_cat 2), 15% between 400.000 and 600.000 (gluc_cat 3) and so on and so forth